# Why does this ClassLoader be used twice?

Tags: java, spring, jvm

#### Background

I want to execute an function that has not been loaded in JVM in a running program.

My program is running on cloud, and I want to dynamically execute an function without redeploying the application.

My mean is writing a customized ClassLoader receiving Class file from my exposed interface, the customized classloader is here:

```
@Slf4j
public class ClassFileClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private final InputStream classFileInputStream;

    public ClassFileClassLoader(InputStream classFileInputStream) {
        this.classFileInputStream = classFileInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        log.info("Class [{}] is going to be loaded.", name);
        //check if this class has been loaded by super ClassLoader
        Class<?> clazz = super.findLoadedClass(name);
        if (clazz == null) {
            byte[] classData = getClassData(); 
            if (classData == null) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException();
            }
            clazz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length); 
        }
        return clazz;
    }

    private byte[] getClassData() {
        try {
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 4];
            int len;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((len = classFileInputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            return baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (classFileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    classFileInputStream.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then I make a task class with a function:

```
public class AnyTask {
    public void afterSaleGoodsOfZD(String acc) {
        AfterSalesDao afterSalesDao = (AfterSalesDao) SpringContextUtil.getBean("afterSalesDao");
        // ... some business logic

    }
}
```

And my exposed interface like this:

```
@PostMapping("/dynamicLoading")
    public void dynamicLoading(@RequestParam("class") MultipartFile classFile, @RequestParam String packagePath,
                               @RequestParam String methodName, @RequestParam Object[] args)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        ClassFileClassLoader classLoader = new ClassFileClassLoader(classFile.getInputStream());
        String className = classFile.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[0];
        Class<?> clazz = classLoader.findClass(packagePath + "." + className);
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                Object o = clazz.newInstance();
                m.invoke(o, args);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

JVM version: 1.8.0_392 (arm64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8"

#### Process

1. Compile the task class AnyTask with javac on local machine.
2. Use the compiled class to invoke the exposed interface

```
curl --location 'http://xxxx/api/task/dynamicLoading' \
--form 'class=@"/xx/xx/xx/AnyTask.class"' \
--form 'packagePath="com.wosai.it.oms.task"' \
--form 'methodName="afterSaleGoodsOfZD"' \
--form 'args="acc"
```

#### Question

The process is totally normal on my local machine, but when it comes to cloud, the problem appears. It will throw an exception "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

With my log `log.info("Class [{}] is going to be loaded.", name);` in ClassFileClassLoader I found that this log was invoked twice:

1. Class [com.wosai.it.oms.task.AnyTask] is going to be load.
2. Class [com.wosai.it.oms.util.SpringContextUtil] is going to be load.
   And it occurred an exception when invoked the second, of course, that must be an exception, because my customized classloader cannot load SpringContextUtil!

But on my local machine, there is only one log printed:

1. Class [com.wosai.it.oms.task.AnyTask] is going to be load.
   So, it's running normally.

I want to know why the same code has different performance in local and cloud?
As my expected, it should be executed normally like local.

Comment: When you get an `InvocationTargetException`, there is an exception thrown by the invoked target, which you should inspect. Besides that, this class loader is broken. Instead of trying to find the class with the specified name, it mindlessly tries to read the class definition from the one `InputStream`. This might be the wrong class for the current request, further, an input stream can only be read once. This method should use the definition only when the class name matches. Or, just invoke `defineClass` in the first place, without overriding and calling `findClass`.

Comment: And you might also want to redirect to the parent `ClassLoader` in case another class is loaded with your `ClassLoader`

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your replies, your ideas are correct, the codes have some deficiencies like you mentioned, I will refine it.

Comment: @dan1st indeed, i need do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class loader defines a class, the JVM will use this defining class loader for resolving all symbolic references. You might not have noticed so far, as the inherited `loadClass` implementation will only delegate to `findClass` if the standard delegation failed.

Since you do not specify a parent loader, the system class loader will be used as delegation target, which might work in your local environment but fail in the cloud environment. You should pass the defining class loader of your own code as target.

So, a correct `findClass` method would only return the specific class when the requested class name matches. But the better approach is not to override `findClass` at all, leave all resolving to the default, but implement a method doing the intended operation in the first place, to define a particular class:

```java
class ClassFileClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    ClassFileClassLoader() {
        super(ClassFileClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    Class<?> defineClass(String name, InputStream source) throws IOException {
        byte[] definition;
        try(InputStream toReadAndClose = source) {
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 4];
            int len;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while((len = toReadAndClose.read(buff)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            definition = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        return super.defineClass(name, definition, 0, definition.length);
    }
}
```

You may have to add `public` modifiers if the class does not reside in the same package as the using code but I’d keep the visibility at minimum.

Then, you may use it like

```java
ClassFileClassLoader classLoader = new ClassFileClassLoader();
String className = classFile.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[0];
Class<?> clazz = classLoader.defineClass(
        packagePath + "." + className, classFile.getInputStream());
Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
        Object o = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        m.invoke(o, args);
        return;
    }
}
```

Note that calling `newInstance()` directly on a `Class` is discouraged (and deprecated with Java 9 and newer). The instance should be created by calling `newInstance()` on a `Constructor` as demonstrated above.

Further, the reading code has been improved to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will adjust my codes as you pointed. But I still have a question  for these words:
"Since you do not specify a parent loader, the system class loader will be used as delegation target, which might work in your local environment but fail in the cloud environment."

I want to know, in general, what causes the system class loader to behave different in Cloud and local?

Comment: The framework you are using may create new class loaders, including the one loading your code, to implement modularization and/or hot deployment mechanisms, etc. So, since classes loaded through the system class loader are globally visible and can never be unloaded, the classes are not made available to the system class loader in such environments, but rather must be loaded through the framework’s custom loader.

Comment: Yes,  I got it, the SpringContextUtil is loaded by org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader, which is a framwork's custom loader. And after I specify the parent class loader for my ClassFileClassLoader as org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader, it works. Thank you buddy.